# UISlider value changed update result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have three labels receiving output from three `UISliders`. A result is calculated and placed in a fourth label when a segmented control is touched.

How do I make the result update if one of the slider values is changed without touching the segmented control again?

Comment: Why wouldnt you simply update the actual result when any of the sliders is slid? On the fly calculation!!!  Also post some of your code so that we can look at it and maybe simply edit it!!!

Answer (score 1):

First, add an event for your slider changing values:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You will want to do this for each slider.

In your `sliderValueChanged:` function:

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
    [self calculateResult];
}
```

In `calculateResult` you can do your calculations and set your result box.

If you need to make sure your segmented control is in some state first, just add an `if` clause to `sliderValueChanged:`

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
    if ([mySegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 1) {
        [self calculateResult];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I came up with something that worked from your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that worked using [mopsled's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11161561/814730):

```
if (UIControlEventValueChanged && mySeg.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    float floatResult = [f3.text floatValue]-[f2.text floatValue];
    float coldFactor = [fcold.text floatValue]*floatResult;
    float result = [f1.text floatValue]+coldFactor;

    NSString *tpResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f",result];
    f4Result.text = tpResult;             
}
```